# How to connect operator $or & $and in couchDb mango?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-mango

I have document in witch has field "leader". Leader can be type string or array. For example `{leader: "id"} or {leader: ["id"]}`. How I can get all document where `leader = id`; If I use operator $all, I search in array, if use operator $or I search in field(string). How  I can to connect them ? I don't want to do two request. Field has differents type because was had changed structure. Thanks.

```
"selector": {
      "leaderId": {
         "$all": ["id"]
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.collection.find({$or : [{"leader" : "id"}, {"leader" : { $all : ["id"] }}]})
```